# Kendo Grid How to create a header row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working with AngularJs 1.5.8, ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and Kendo Grid 2016 v3.914.
I have a view with a grid on it that is grouped just fine.

But now I need to add a row in between each group.  The row will have one column but span all columns.  I know what field I want.
I just don't know how to code my controller to show the column.

Can you help?

Thanks 
BTD

Here is me code so far.

```
            return {
                toolbar: ["excel", "pdf", { name: "exportCSV", template: "<a class='k-button k-button-iicontext k-grid-exportCSV' ng-click='vm.currentRatesKendoGridToCSV(vm.rateType)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span> Export to CSV</a>" }],
                excel: { fileName: "AdvanceRates.xlsx", allPages: true },
                pdf: {
                    avoidLinks: true,
                    allPages: true,
                    fileName: "AdvanceRates.pdf"
                },
                group: [{ field: 'ParentName' }, { field: 'Id' }, { field: 'SortBy' }, { field: 'Name' }],
                //group: { field: 'ParentName','Id','SortBy','Name', aggregates: [ { field: "Name"}] },
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false,
                columns: [
                        {
                            title: 'Instrument',
                            field: 'Instrument',
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Rate',
                            field: 'Rate',
                            format: '{0:0.000%}'
                        },
                ]
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a `groupHeaderTemplate`.

```
columns: [{
              title: 'Instrument',
              field: 'Instrument',
              groupHeaderTemplate: "This is my dividing line...",
          },
```

example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@sg53719/UdIxU

Answer (score 0):

I answered it myself.
In my javascript controller code where I am setting the data source, I added this code  group: { field: 'Name' },  and now I see the grouping.